# Django - Rendering Inclusion Tag from a View

Tags: django, django-templates

so I was wondering if you could return an inclusion tag directly from a view.

The page is a normal page with a list of items.  The list of items is rendered using an inclusion tag.  If an ajax request is made to the view, I want to return only what the inclusion tag would return so I can append it onto the page via javascript.  Is something like this possible? Or should I architect this better?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for the render_to_string or render_to_response shortcuts:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response

We can still use the inclusion tag to generate a template context dict from our args (as helpfully pointed out by @BobStein-VisiBone in comments)

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from .templatetags import my_inclusion_tag


rendered = render_to_string('my_include.html', my_inclusion_tag(foo='bar'))

#or

def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response('my_include.html',
                      my_inclusion_tag(foo='bar'),
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Doing it this way meands that you have to repeat the name of the template to be rendered in your view, which breaks the DRY principle

Comment: @Craig getting the DRY back is trivial, just store the name of the template in a variable and use the var in both your view and where the inclusion tag is defined

Comment: Not that the O.P. gave any example to start with, but what's missing from yours is any mention of the inclusion tag function. Turns out that even though it's decorated, it can still be called directly to output a dictionary ready for render_to_string(). I suggest replacing both dictionaries in your code with:  `my_inclusion_tag_function(arguments)` and add at the top `from templatetags.my_file include my_inclusion_tag_function` or something.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty way could be to have a view, that renders a template, that only contains your templatetag.

Comment: ya, this way seemed to be redundant in code, was hoping for something that didn't involve that extra step.

Comment: then expose the serialised models as json , check out http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/ for a start, or roll your own app, use a different URL namespace rather than branching in your existing views though!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the exact same thing today, and ended up writing a helper function to render template tags:

```
def render_templatetag(request, tag_string, tag_file, dictionary=None):
    dictionary = dictionary or {}
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    context_instance.update(dictionary)
    t = Template("{%% load %s %%}{%% %s %%}" % (tag_file, tag_string))
    return t.render(context_instance)
```

tag_string is the call to the template tag as it'd appear in a normal template, and tag_file is the file you need to load for the template tag.

Comment: this is quite pointless, the tag rendering should be done in a template rather than in view code. you can use the include tag to avoid duplicating template code.

Comment: Doing it this way meands that you don't have to repeat the name of the template to be rendered in your view

Comment: @Craig yeah but you have to repeat the tag string used in the template in your view instead, it's no more DRY

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but probably bit hacky, complex or complicated.

What I would suggest, is architect it so that you have the rendering part in utils.py function and use it in a simple_tag instead of an inclusion_tag. This way you can then use the same utils rendering function easily in views.

In my (very simplified) imaginary example I have listing of users and a "Load more" button that returns more users.

**account/utils.py**

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


def render_users(users):
    return render_to_string("account/user_list_items.html", {"users": users})
```

**account/templatetags/account_tags.py**

```
from django import template

from ..utils import render_users

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def list_users(users):
    return render_users(users)
```

**account/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import User
from .utils import render_users


def load_more_users(request):
    limit = request.GET["limit"]
    offset = request.GET["offset"]
    users = User.objects.all()[offset:offset + limit]
    return HttpResponse(render_users(users))
```

*Simple is better than complex.*

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. A view can render any template that an inclusion tag can. The advantage of this approach is that you can leverage the full strength of Django's templates.

On the other hand AJAX responses typically do not contain HTML so much as XML/JSON. If you are using Django's template features you are better off with returning HTML. If not, XML/JSON might make more sense. Just my two cents.

Comment: I've always had a problem with returning xml/json and then having javascript render the data into html.  Isn't that violating the DRY principles cause now we have the code duplicated in the django template and in the javascript.

Comment: You mention it can be done, but you don't include an example.  Can you show me how to do it or a page that has it?

Answer (score 0):

Using [inclusion tag with configurable template decorator provided by Gonz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490059/django-inclusion-tag-with-configurable-template) instead of default Django's inclusion tags you can write a helper in your view:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from home.templatetags.objectwidgets import object_widget

def _object_widget(request, obj):
    template, context = object_widget(RequestContext(request), obj)
    return render_to_string(template, context)
```

It's DRY and works with Django 1.3 (I haven't tested it with Django 1.4).

I use this technique to return search results rendered in HTML via JSON/AJAX calls (nothing better which I came up with).