# How can I make my Django TemplateTags less repetitive?

Tags: django, templates, dry, django-templates

I have some templatetags in a Django app with the same function for different tags / templates.

Foo tag goes to foo_template.html, and boo tag goes to boo_template.html, for example:

Foo tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('foo_template.html', takes_context=True)
def foo(context, something):    
    sometng = something
    return {'something': sometng}
```

Boo tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('boo_template.html', takes_context=True)
def boo(context, something):    
    sometng = something
    return {'something': sometng}
```

How can I make my code DRYer? Is there a better way of registering tags in this case?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9415589/1628832) should give you an idea

Comment: The methods seem identical. Are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, a decorator is just syntactic sugar for a wrapping function which takes the original as an argument. So you could leave your context function undecorated, then define two wrappers:

```
def common(context, something):    
    sometng = something
    return {'something': sometng}

register.inclusion_tag('foo_template.html', takes_context=True, name='foo')(common)
register.inclusion_tag('boo_template.html', takes_context=True, name='bar')(common)
```

Comment: {% foo "test" %} is giving me:

    TemplateSyntaxError at /test/
    Invalid block tag: 'foo', expected 'elif', 'else' ou 'endif'

Comment: Apologies, with this you'll need to explicitly pass the name parameter, see update above.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted!!