# How do I register a "dynamic" inclusion tag within Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags, inclusion

How do I use Django's "inclusion tags" to pull a dynamic template based on an argument provided to a View?

I'm creating a "Download" page for content on my website. Many different pieces of content can be downloaded, and I want to use just one View for the Download page that pulls in optional parameters from urls.py:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^download/download-1/$', base_views.download, {
        'name':'download-1',
        'title':'Download 1',
        'url':'https://sample-download-location.com/download-1.zip',
        'upsell':'upsell-1'
    }
),

url(r'^download/download-2/$', base_views.download, {
        'name':'download-2',
        'title':'Download 2',
        'url':'https://sample-download-location.com/download-2.zip',
        'upsell':'upsell-2'
    }
),
```

**views.py**

```
def download(request, name, title, url, upsell):
return render(request, 'base/pages/download/download.html', {
        'title': title,
        'url': url,
        'upsell': upsell,
    }
)
```

**download.html Part 1**

The information from this View will then be piped into a Download template like so:

```
<div id="thank-you-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Download <em>{{ title }}</em></h1>
        <p>Thanks for purchasing <em>{{ title }}</em>! You can download it here:</p>
        <p><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="{{ url }}">Download Now</a></p>
        <p>And afterwards, be sure to check out...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the tricky part: at the bottom of the download.html page, I want to have an inclusion tag that dynamically populates based on the page specified in the 'upsell' paramter — something along these lines:

**download.html Part 2**

```
{% upsell %}
```

I then want this tag to pull from my base_extras.py file dynamically depending on the 'upsell' page that has been specified:

**base_extras.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('base/pages/upsell-1.html')
    def upsell_1_content():
        return

@register.inclusion_tag('base/pages/upsell-2.html')
    def upsell_2_content():
        return
```

This way, if "upsell-1" is specified, the "upsell-1.html" template is served; if "upsell-2" is specified, the "upsell-2.html" template is served.

However, when I do the above, I get a TemplateError. Is there an easy way to serve up a template dynamically like what I'm trying to do above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490059/django-inclusion-tag-with-configurable-template)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! To solve this, I ditched inclusion tags completely and used the vanilla {% include %} tag, which pulls in the contents of an external template directly and passes in the context of the current template.

My code now looks like this: urls.py and views.py, above, remain unchanged. No code is necessary in base_extras.py. Only download.html is changed:

**download.html**

```
<div id="thank-you-content">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Download <em>{{ title }}</em></h1>
    <p>Thanks for purchasing <em>{{ title }}</em>! You can download it here:</p>
    <p><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="{{ url }}">Download Now</a></p>
    <p>And afterwards, be sure to check out...</p>
</div>
</div>
{% include upsell %}
```